# Postgres: Store result of a query into a variable and use that variable in another query

Tags: postgresql, variables, dbeaver

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6 with a query that roughly looks like this:

```
DO $$
DECLARE max_sales_date DATE ;
BEGIN

max_sales_date :=

select sales_date::date 
from (
     select count(sales_date::date)
        , sales_date::date
        , row_number() over (order by count(sales_date::date) desc) as rn 
     from Sales
     group by sales_date::date
     ) a where a.rn = 1 ;

select *
from Sales
where sales_date = max_sales_date ;

END $$ ;
```

As you can see, I want to get the day with the highest number of sales, store it in a variable and use it in another query. I am aware that a variable is not necessary in that case but I need this for another step whose development has not started yet.

DBeaver 5.0 unfortunately throws me the following error message:

> Internal jdbc driver error
>
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutofBoundsExcception:

I also have to mention that the query whose result is stored in the variable works fine when used independently.

I therefore have two questions:

1. Why doesn't the whole code work?
2. How can I reach the result I want?

EDIT: the below comments made me realize I should clarify my intentions: The reason why I'd like to keep using a variable is because I was planning to perform some simple computations on it afterwards (e.g. add one day, create a loop, etc.). If you guys can find an easy solution for this without using a variable, I'd be glad too :)

Comment: Can you add the stack trace to the query?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'm afraid I don't know what it is and how I can get that.

Comment: That's the long list of method names that usually follows the error message in Java.

Comment: In order to find an easier solution you would need to present the _actual_ problem you are trying to solve. Re-using the max value can be done using a CTE. But apparently that isn't the only thing you want to do

Answer (score -2):

You can use select ... into pattern, and you can't have a "select *" query in a DO function - it is not meant to return a query.

```
DO $$
DECLARE max_sales_date DATE ;
declare sale record;
BEGIN

select sales_date into max_sales_date  from 
(select sales_date from (select count(sales_date) as cnt, sales_date::date 
    from Sales group by sales_date) as dt order by cnt desc limit 1) as ct;

for sale in select * from Sales where sales_date = max_sales_date
loop
-- do whatever is needed with this data
end loop;

END $$ ;
```

Comment: The OP said: *I am aware that a variable is not necessary in that case but I need this for another step whose development has not started yet.*

Comment: Edited the query, in a way that the variable is preserved.

Comment: But that does exactly the same as the question. Do you think that won't throw an exception? Well, @Guillaume can answer that.

Comment: I was guessing that this "select *" would be part of something that is not ready. When I test the code above, the error occours on the select * part - you should "do something" with this select, as the do block could not return the data. Changing the code to a fully functional one.